# Matlab matlabpool function undefined

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I am try to use the matlab parallel computing feature.
I first typed "ver" to check if I have already installed Parallel Computing Toolbox, it did

```
>> ver
----------------------------------------------------------------------------     
MATLAB Version: 9.0.0.341360 (R2016a)
MATLAB License Number: 353265
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise Version 10.0 (Build 10240)
Java Version: Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-        
Bit Server VM mixed mode
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
....
Parallel Computing Toolbox              Version 6.8        (R2016a)
....
```

So it seems that I have already installed it. But when I try to use it, it just doesn't work

```
>> matlabpool('open',2);
Undefined function or variable 'matlabpool'.

>> matlabpool open
Undefined function or variable 'matlabpool'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command ([as of R2013b](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/release-notes.html#R2013b)) is [`parpool`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parpool.html) to create the pool of workers.

```
parpool(2)
```